# what is efficient way to assign values from rows to properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I am using LINQ
I have a Configuration table to store key values it has 30 settings in 30 rows
For eg:

```
 setting       value
    A            2
    B           "xyz" 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
 and so on
```

I have created Property class to hold all values from database.

I want to hold these settings in property class

so in which way i can fetch and set all these properties.

Do i have to loop through all rows and set properties one by one

or what are your efficient suggestions

Comment: Is this a `DataTable` or `Linq-Sql`?

Comment: use any key value pair collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800/best-implementation-for-key-value-pair-data-structure

Answer (score 4):

Read the table and load it into a Dictionary.
Use the setting as Key and the Value as value.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("A", "2");
dictionary.Add("B", "xyz");
```

Then when you need a setting you can just perform

```
var settingA = Int.Parse(dictionary["A"]);
var settingB = dictionary["B"]
```

So now you can do:

```
Objectset.SettingEntities.ForEach(x => dictionary.Add(x.setting, x.value));
```

This is less overhead then loading every field into it's own property, because then you will have to assign each value manually and do the required checking.